# Tabulating the CDF for an exponential

Tags: r, probability-density, cdf

I want to make a table with the CDF of an poisson, anyone have any idea how I can start? I want it to look something like the following and stop still P(X) is 0.99.

X  P(X)

1   XZ
2   XZ
3   XZ

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The exponential distribution is continuous. Do you want `P(x<=X)` or something like that? Maybe `data.frame(x=0:5) |> transform(p=pexp(x))` will give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I actually meant to put a discrete distribution like the poisson, do you have any tips for this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Replace `pexp` with `ppois`

Comment: You will have to add a value for `lambda` since there is no default. For example `matrix(c(0:10, round(ppois(0:10, 1), 4)), ncol=2)`.